# truffle migrate (deploy) fails with gas issues

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am trying to deploy contracts using truffle framework. I have multiple contracts, all of them are linked appropriately.

### Example:

Governance contract is the main contract. There are other individual contracts which are imported and used in Governance contract.

### Infrastructure:

1) geth version - 1.6
2) truffle version - 3.3.1

I am using a private chain to deploy a contract.I have purposely set a higher

```
gas limit in genesis JSON file
    "gasLimit": "900000000000",


While deploying - in truffle.js I have set very high gas limit as 

    staging: {
      host: "192.168.100.5",
      port: 8001,   // Different than the default below
      network_id: 1407,
      gas:799999999999
//      gasPrice:1000000000000
     }
```

In spite of high gas limit, truffle deployment fails with following error. I am not sure how to proceed

Using network 'staging'.

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  Migrations: 0x15dce2e6ad79f7d6bc7d40c746b1f9604f7d2566
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying Purchase...
  Purchase: 0x2c0b177a1e272a3cc939c8a3d96482e44742e90e
  Deploying SellerWarehouse...
  SellerWarehouse: 0x73f628469da45dd241034c7c1f2bca4236e3cf98
  Deploying AdvisingBankRegistry...
  AdvisingBankRegistry: 0x09b2f07473b578d85945c42cef7d6681a5aa28de
  Deploying IssuingBankRegistry...
  IssuingBankRegistry: 0xa59de5dced25f414be5eb982ed4d52d01349e8b9
  Deploying BuyerRegistry...
  BuyerRegistry: 0x665c371ef610e64035536e812938363044d7c113
  Deploying CarrierRegistry...
  CarrierRegistry: 0x822fd29dfb933a7e2bf2f0710b52bdca4d0ef474
  Deploying Governance...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
    at Object.callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:204860:46)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:31793:25
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:206693:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:205469:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:207342:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:207632:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:207787:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:207747:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

One fix could be - Breaking your migration file into multiple. For instance, in this case, 2_deploy_contracts.js seems to have 7 contracts deployments.

I've faced the similar issue before and breaking migration files into multiple fixes this issue in some cases.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is getting the error:

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

Delete the `./build` directory and enable the solc optimizer in `truffle.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 8545, // Using ganache as development network
            network_id: "*",
            gas: 4698712,
            gasPrice: 25000000000
        }
    },
    solc: {
        optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200
        }
    }
};
```